# Blogger to WordPress URl issues

Tags: wordpress

I have just converted a blogger site to WordPress. Unfortunately URLs are not same for both the sites. Now I need to add redirects for all google cached URLs. But I am not able to get all the google cached URL's at one place so that i can check them all.

Please advise?

Comment: How did URLs change? Any examples? Theoretically it should be possible to make the change seamless, i.e. no change visible to the outside.

Comment: I got the solution. Thank for your time. Here is the link :http://rtcamp.com/blogger-to-wordpress/tutorials/permalink-seo-migration/

Comment: Feel free to post that as an answer yourself and mark it as the solution. Better than keeping the question "open".